# How can my library import another library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, exception, import, aar

I am starting with libraries in Android, and I have managed to import a library in my app in this way:

1. add the .aar file in the /libs folder
2. add in build.gradle:

   ```
   repositories{
     flatDir {
       dirs'libs'
   }
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile(name:'mylibrary1',ext:'aar')
   }
   ```

This works fine, but I made `mylibrary2` and repeated steps 1 and 2 in `mylibrary1`, so now `mylibrary1` could use `mylibrary2`.

In summary I want my app to import `mylibrary1` and `mylibrary1` to import `mylibrary2`.

The problem is in my app when I call a method from `mylibrary2` I get an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, I hope someone can help me

Here is the stackstrace in case it helps:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: ar.com.tally.myapplication, PID: 30197
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lar/com/tally/mylibrary2/Class2;
     at ar.com.tally.mylibrary1.Class1.get1(Class1.java:10)
     at ar.com.tally.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ar.com.tally.mylibrary2.Class2" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.2.1_d668123607e57c7aa4406ba98a4276e21606428b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.2.1_eca880fd3aaa2f093d820f9d7b8841aa1fa00b4f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-intermediates-exploded-aar-mylibrary1_7763b008eb2396101d055fb29b3e03d5ee273add-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.2.1_5e6bcbbe4699b2a562a7ba7b6349f8bbfbef9fb4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.2.1_c564c185a6a1edef108674e96bf4712114e0c95a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-recyclerview-v7-23.2.1_a1ec4cea5854a30b896e5f639d2fd95cd214b2b1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-design-23.2.1_2c4b9902e86719e2bd0652ddfba695894bed0a47-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.2.1_01059d3db947a24736ebcedd233fd40b734ccf3e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ar.com.tally.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.2.1_69d3f470bac3bccd2f54179c6363fce8b9091976-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
     at ar.com.tally.mylibrary1.Class1.get1(Class1.java:10) 
     at ar.com.tally.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ar.com.tally.mylibrary2.Class2" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ar.com.tally.myapplication-1
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile modules in your project, or actual .aar files from the `lib/` folder?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. I have the .aar files that I created from other Android Libraries. The .aar files that are generated in buid/outputs/aar/.

Comment: In Android Studio, do you have modules for your libraries? If so, then you can use the answer below. Otherwise, where does `compile(name:'mylibrary1',ext:'aar')` come from? Do you have a file named `mylibrary1.aar` somewhere?

Comment: Does `mylibrary1` call methods or use classes in `mylibrary2`? If not, simply allow it to be a dependency of the app itself like library1.

Answer (score 1):

So when you made mylibrary2 you changed mylibrary1 also so you need to replace both aars with the new ones clean and build again.

However if you have those libs in the same project as modules i recommend that you import them as projects instead of coping manually.

`compile project(':mylibrary1')
compile project(':mylibrary2')`

or if in different projects as in this case you can add mavenLocal() in repositories:

```
    repositories {
     mavenLocal()
...
}
```

and in your lib projects you can add the maven plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

then you need to call:

> gradle install

which will install the libs in your local maven repo. so you don't need to copy them manually

Comment: thanks , yes I have them as modules in one proyect, but when I want to use them in other proyect I got the .aar file and paste it in /libs

Comment: also in my app i only pasted mylibrary1.aar, I think this would include mylibrary2

Comment: no you have include both aars :) howver check my edited answer i added another useful option u can use

Comment: where should call gradle install?

Comment: in you command line or on the gradle tasks window. you have to install both libs so if you have a project with both libs as modules calling it on the project will do the same as calling it for each lib

Comment: I will try to install gradle, cause the command line doesnt work

Comment: try to run .gradlew or gradlew.bat if on wondows